# Project a cylindrical surface onto a 2D rectangular grid

Tags: coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

Maybe I am over-analyzing my problem, but hopefully someone can offer some advice.

I'm currently doing some experiments, where I have a series of measurement sites along the inside of a cylinder (in the z direction). Each "site" (along z) consists of a series of measurement points located around the inside tube circumference (defined by r, theta). I know the co-ordinates of each measurements point. Now, I want to project each measurement point from the cylindrical surface onto a 2D rectangular grid to generate a map of the measurements, but I am unsure how to do this. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How about just plotting $(z,\theta)$?

Comment: Ya, I could do that I suppose. I was probably over-complicating the problem! Cheers